# Getting error saying "Registering a component with a id (`form1`) which has already been used"

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am getting this error, when i click the same button for more than 1 time. What does this suggest, and what should i do to prevent it;

```
[WARN] [WARN][Ext.Component#constructor] Registering a component with a id (`form1`) which has already been used. Please ensure the existing component has been destroyed (`Ext.Component#destroy()`.
2012-05-08 21:29:56.869 ProjectSeal[870:fb03] [WARN] [WARN][Ext.Component#constructor] Registering a component with a id (`new-note-btn1`) which has already been used. Please ensure the existing component has been destroyed (`Ext.Component#destroy()`.
```

According to the error/warning, how can i `destroy` the component ?

**UPDATE**

```
Ext.define('app.view.Contact',{
           extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
           xtype:'contactform',
           id: 'form1',
....
```

How do i let Sencha add id's to my code ?

**UPDATE**

> [WARN] [DEPRECATE][Anonymous] itemId is deprecated as a property
>   directly on the Component. Please put it inside the config object, and
>   retrieve it using "this.config.itemId"

Answer (score 3):

You most likely create a window or form object when user clicks the button. During creation looks like you're assigning hardcoded `id` to this component.

You need either to make sure previously used form destroyed (check `closeAction` property for example) or don't assign `id` property yourself and let Sencha do this.

Comment: How do i let Sencha assign id property ? and i have updated my post. please have a look

Comment: But, i use `var values = Ext.getCmp('form1').getValues();` to get the form values of the view. If i remove `form1` then i will not be able to get the values.

Comment: It says `itemId` is deprecated.

Comment: Where? Nothing here http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-cfg-itemId indicates that

Comment: I have updated my post, with the deprecated error message i got.

Answer (score 1):

[WARN] [DEPRECATE][Anonymous] itemId is deprecated as a property directly on the Component. Please put it inside the config object, and retrieve it using "this.config.itemId"

Place itemId within config.

eg:

```
config: {

    itemId: 'form1',

    // other config options

}
```